# FastAPI+docker+nginx static css don't work

Tags: css, docker, nginx, docker-compose, fastapi

With this parameters everything work's fine except CSS from static files

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

On my ps css works well

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main_landing.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but on VPS server with docker and nginx it's fail css and type ***backend*** in url

```
<link href="http://backend/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i can't understand why all pages loads normal, but css url convert to **backend**

Docker-compose-ci.yaml

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  # nginx service
  web:
    container_name: "nginx"
    image: nginx:alpine
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - custom

  # application service
  app:
    container_name: "app"
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - custom

networks:
  custom:
    driver: bridge
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

NGINX config

```
upstream backend {
    server app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

}
```

I already try change backend in config nginx file to ip server address or 127.0.0.1  or 0.0.0.0  with ports or without but it's only broke nginx to 403 or 502 errors

Comment: give a try and see: open `/etc/hosts` and add this line `127.0.0.1 backend`